# How to implement MSMQ Triggers

Tags: c#, msmq

Do anybody can solve my problem?

I wanna fire one event when some data is inserted in MSMQ queue how i can do it?

Comment: Why aren't you using the MSMQ Triggers service?

Answer (score 5):

You create your instance of the message queue and start peeking at it asynchronously:

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue( @".\PRIVATE$\Queue" );
queue.BeginPeek( TimeSpan.Infinite, null, OnMessageAdded);
```

The registered callback is called when a message was added to the queue. As far as you did not explain what your real problem is, I assume you want to get informed about new messages added to the queue:

```
private void OnMessageAdded( IAsyncResult ar )
{
    Message peekedMessage = queue.EndPeek(ar);
    //Do whatever you want. Raise a new event, process the message, ...
}
```

The message is not taken off the queue. You can use the message, but it still remains in the queue. So if you don't need the Message, you can simply call `queue.EndPeek(ar);` without using the result.

Comment: Thanks for the help..The function invoked after receiving from MSMQ here if i am not wrong .. I want to invoke a function when something is inserted in MSMQ..

Comment: Sorry, please use BeginPeek and EndPeek. I will correct the answer.

Comment: Noticed a few things: `TimeSpan.Infinite` does not exist in the newer .NET versions, however, the `BeginPeek` method does not work with infinite timeout, max value is 50 days.